# Error in createWorkbook(type = ext) : Unknown format Data in R

Tags: r, dataset, save, xlsx

I used R to make a dataset consisting of 9 columns, 2 of them are characters and the rest are numeric, and for that I used the command data.frame
I want to save the dataset in my computer in an excel file so I am using th following code:

```
write.xlsx(new_data, file)
```

where file is the destination I want to save it. I've tried that command several times ago and it was working perfectly but this time I am getting an error back saying:

```
Error in createWorkbook(type = ext) : Unknown format Data
```

I don't know what to do to fix that problem. I've downloaded the corresponding package to use that command and I am using the library too, so that is not the problem.

Part of the dataset looks like that:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020), Month = c("April", "August", "December", "February", 
"January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", "October", 
"September", "February", "January", "March", "April", "August", 
"December", "February", "January"), Country = c("Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium"
), Yearly_Avg = c(16.8744280559468, 16.5742978691062, 19.7582603823048, 
20.0995113726207, 22.159638908606, 16.3921228601795, 16.0600580144822, 
18.0429069983406, 16.1335324637284, 19.3313366495739, 18.1576751355617, 
17.7576825704506, 20.5023364228561, 20.4796477705191, 21.8839427966824, 
17.5093947635307, 16.8244128304848, 18.2986763058834, 17.6349268331471, 
19.3710576260764), Monthly_Avg = c(17.5439477479378, 15.9341820502547, 
17.530722007165, 15.8389913543081, 20.5105660799249, 16.2600932619789, 
9.87181304501773, 17.1856966348436, 15.0898542839449, 18.3777431503772, 
15.8249359315534, 16.3004100301265, 20.3146212543137, 18.642219655174, 
20.9761885859812, 19.8377753973291, 16.8487709028363, 15.2106954951857, 
15.5311747851574, 17.1658612678814), Weekly_Avg= c(7.10475853031207, 
6.11148507770456, 7.85609336456891, 6.55222253962218, 9.43989731346756, 
5.81589613640666, 5.19628464098288, 7.22802554102707, 5.80143233950403, 
8.13800967670196, 6.48376157165925, 6.32095532711856, 8.68986433237802, 
8.39290625115118, 9.15735048128797, 15.9512610874645, 11.3482807319524, 
12.7782717870906, 11.3638932656897, 14.7351012362691), Price_1 = c(28.4611003454724, 
35.6054984184222, 39.2081812263157, 0, 0, 26.230988052438, 27.2078733696025, 
30.2269874357209, 22.9303758469904, 52.7661622570557, 36.3581735319494, 
32.9769837451705, 18.4098585648499, 37.7051687645876, NA, 36.1320055593011, 
41.0302230604013, 38.583355656882, 5.83773044716594, 0), Price_2 = c(18.8790737297885, 
6.22257626807137, 26.4138764718301, 0, 0, 3.46573590279973, 11.3777927909787, 
6.95654544315157, 11.8168745098859, 28.9183654237345, 15.3226286604391, 
9.44145209293957, 11.3328054829311, 23.6779310397014, NA, 29.4627378650933, 
17.784291897211, 25.8144436031916, 0, 0), Price_3 = c(5.1, 5.6, 
6.1, 4.9, 4.3, 5.9, 6.2, 4.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5.2, 5.6, NA, 5.5, NA, 
4.9, 6.6, 5.8, 5.1, 5.2)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the code I used is

```
new_data <- data.frame("Year" = data1$Year, "Month"= data1$Month, "Country" = data1$Country, "Week" = data1$Weekly_Avg, "Monthly_Avg" = Monthly_Avg, "Yearly_Avg" = Yearly_Avh, "Price1" = data2$Price_1, "Price2" = data2$Price_2, "Price3" = data2$Price_3)

write.xlsx(new_data, "C:/Users/MK/Documents/Project/Data")
```

I took those data from different datasets and after putting them together the format of it was grouped_df. I tried to make it a dataframe as shown above but I still can't save it in an excel file.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Or any other idea on how to save that dataset on my computer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please include the dataset and the code used? [MRE] provides useful guidance on what best to include in a question.

Comment: I just upload some more information. I hope is useful. Thank you

Comment: Hi could you paste the data into the question using `dput(new_data)` so it can be copied easily? or `dput(head(new_data, 20))` if the data set is large; check the sample data causes the error otherwise it will not help.

Comment: Try `write.xlsx(new_data, "C:/Users/MK/Documents/Project/Data.xlsx")`

Comment: @Peter I've tried that but unfortunately it doesn't change anything! I also updated the data I have on the post. Thank you

Comment: Are all the folders created prior to saving? I ran `write.xlsx(new_data, "Data.xlsx")` which saved the file in the r project directory no problem. I'm not sure that `xlsx` with create a directory path if it is not already created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the output name. The extension 'xlsx'is needed.

write.xlsx(new_data, "C:/Users/MK/Documents/Project/Data.xlsx")

I had the same problem and that solved it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the ".xlsx" extension is needed. However, if you have your path already defined there's no need to write it out in the command:

```
write.xlsx(new_data, "Data.xlsx")
```

and if you want to put it in its own folder you can simply add it before the name (ie folder name "New Data"):

```
write.xlsx(new_data, "New Data/Data.xlsx")
```